# Detect collision between shape and Kinetic.Group

Tags: collision-detection, kineticjs, collision

The shape that I'm moving is a rectangle with `width:40` and `height:4`, and this is what made the detection harder. It's easier when width = height (you can see the collision between the big rectangles).

In my case, I need to detect collision between this rectangle, and a group containing another rectangle, then add the small one to the group. Here's a fiddle to understand more: http://jsfiddle.net/4Y87X/6/

It works great when collision is detected on bottom, and on the right of the group, but the left and top borders are not well "detected".

Comment: You might simplify your code by creating a window.clone ahead of time and placing it directly over the original window.

Comment: Right, I edited it, but how do I do to get the correct behavior as described?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that you've refactored your code to pre-create your window.clone you can use this `dragend` handler to either assign the clone to a group or to reposition the clone back on top of the original window element.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/p4bYB/

```
clone.on("dragend",function(){
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var x=parseInt(pos.x);
    var y=parseInt(pos.y);
    var gPos=group.position();
    var gSize=group.getSize();
    if(x>gPos.x && x<gPos.x+gSize.width && y>gPos.y && y<gPos.y+gSize.height){
        this.moveTo(group);
        thisPos=this.position();
        this.position({x:thisPos.x-gPos.x,y:thisPos.y-gPos.y});
    }else{
        this.moveTo(layer);
        this.position(window.position());
    }
    layer.draw();
});
```

**[ Per additional comment, reposition dropped clone to group's top-left after dropping ]**

If you want the clone to be positioned to top-left of group when added just do this:

```
this.moveTo(group);
this.position(0,0);
```

Comment: This just does the test if the window.clone is inside the group, then add it, else remove, which is already implemented in the solution (if you comment the line `cw.dragBoundFunc(dragBoundWindow);` and write `this.remove();` . My question was how to fix the "rotation" and snap to the top and left borders of the big rectangle, to be behaving like the right and bottom borders. I think it's about adding +window.height() somewhere.

Comment: I'm confused! You don't mention anything about "rotation" or "snapping" in your question.  Your code fails to drop the clone in the group so I thought that was your issue.

Comment: Exactly, and this is due to some error in the math equations when detecting collision and inverting width/height. Sorry I couldn't describe my problem well. I was trying to switch width and height in order to make a "snapping" functionality, like jQuery snap property.